# Converting a case class hierarchy to scalaz.Tree with Shapeless

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

Consider the following hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Ex
case class Lit(value: Int) extends Ex
case class Var(name: Char) extends Ex
case class Add(a: Ex, b: Ex) extends Ex
```

I'd like to convert expressions such as `val ex = Add(Lit(0),Add(Lit(1),Var('a')))` into a `scalaz.Tree[Either[Class[Any],Any]]]`, which in this case would give:

```
-\/(class Add)
|
+- -\/(class Lit)
|  |
|  `- \/-(0)
|
`- -\/(class Add)
   |
   +- -\/(class Lit)
   |  |
   |  `- \/-(1)
   |
   `- -\/(class Var)
      |
      `- \/-(a)
```

Which is the most appropriate Shapeless functionality/example to start from for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for a disclaimer: if you're planning to use this in real code, I think it's almost certainly a bad idea. It'd be better to try to use Shapeless to do what you're trying to do directly rather than going through this type-unsafe representation. But it's a fun problem, so here goes.

(Oh, and another disclaimer: this implementation is off the top of head and there may be nicer ways to accomplish this.)

First for a helper type class (note that all of the code in the three sections below will need to be defined together—you can use `:paste` if you're in a REPL):

```
import scalaz.{ Show, Tree, \/ }, scalaz.syntax.either._
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.ToTraversable

trait TreeifyCc[A, C] {
  def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: C): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any]
}

trait LowPriorityTreeifyCc {
  implicit def singleMemberTreeifyCc[A, C, R <: HList, X](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    ev: R <:< (X :: HNil)
   ): TreeifyCc[A, C] = new TreeifyCc[A, C] {
    def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: C): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] = Tree.Node(
      c.getClass.left,
      Stream(Tree.Leaf(ev(gen.to(c)).head.right))
    )
  }
}

object TreeifyCc extends LowPriorityTreeifyCc {
  implicit def recursiveTreeifyCc[A, C, R <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
    ts: ToTraversable.Aux[R, Stream, A]
  ): TreeifyCc[A, C] = new TreeifyCc[A, C] {
    def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: C): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] =
      Tree.Node(c.getClass.left, ts(gen.to(c)).map(tf(_)))
  }
}
```

And another helper type class:

```
trait TreeifyAdt[A, C] {
  def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: C): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any]
}

object TreeifyAdt {
  implicit def cnilTreeifyAdt[A]: TreeifyAdt[A, CNil] =
    new TreeifyAdt[A, CNil] {
      def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: CNil): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] =
        sys.error("impossible")
    }

  implicit def cconsAdt[A, H, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    cc: TreeifyCc[A, H],
    ta: TreeifyAdt[A, T]
  ): TreeifyAdt[A, H :+: T] = new TreeifyAdt[A, H :+: T] {
    def apply(tf: Treeify[A], c: H :+: T): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] = c match {
      case Inl(h) => cc(tf, h)
      case Inr(t) => ta(tf, t)
    }
  }
}
```

And the type class we actually care about:

```
trait Treeify[A] {
  def apply(a: A): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any]
}

object Treeify {
  implicit def treeifyAdt[A, R <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
    adt: TreeifyAdt[A, R]
  ): Treeify[A] = new Treeify[A] {
    def apply(a: A): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] = adt(this, gen.to(a))
  }

  def toTree[A](a: A)(implicit tf: Treeify[A]): Tree[Class[_] \/ Any] = tf(a)
}
```

And we can use it like this:

```
scala> val ex: Ex = Add(Lit(0), Add(Lit(1), Var('a')))
ex: Ex = Add(Lit(0),Add(Lit(1),Var(a)))

scala> Treeify.toTree(ex).drawTree(scalaz.Show.showFromToString)
res0: String =
"-\/(class Add)
|
+- -\/(class Lit)
|  |
|  `- \/-(0)
|
`- -\/(class Add)
   |
   +- -\/(class Lit)
   |  |
   |  `- \/-(1)
   |
   `- -\/(class Var)
      |
      `- \/-(a)
"
```

This will work for any ADT where all of the leaves either have a single member or one or more recursive members.

Comment: I just realized that I may have overgeneralized from your example and you may have intended this to work for case classes with more than one member. It wouldn't be too hard to adapt the code above to work that way.